# SQL - Selecting from two separate datasets and associating with the same user? Multiple select/from statements in one query?

Tags: sql

I'm having an issue with my report that is pulling the amount of time spent and total tickets for each user.

The issue is with the "TotalTickets" subquery. I have to run a subquery because in order to obtain the TotalTickets, I have to pull from a separate dataset:

```
"FROM tickets JOIN users"
```

To get the tickets.time_spent I also have to pull from a separate dataset:

`"FROM tickets LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_work ON ticket_work.ticket_id = tickets.id JOIN users"`

I can write two completely separate SQL report but I want to combine it in the same report, which is why I'm taking this approach. Here is what I have:

---

```
select users, tickets.time_spent, (select count(tickets.id) FROM tickets 
JOIN users where tickets.assigned_to = users.id) as TotalTickets
FROM tickets LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_work ON ticket_work.ticket_id = tickets.id 
JOIN users where tickets.assigned_to = users.id
```

---

The issue with this is it doesn't associate the TotalTickets count with the user (select users). The tickets.time_spent column works fine though.

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You do not need a `JOIN` in your sub-query.  Just COUNT for the current user.

Comment: Your explain is unclear, I think something you missed. From your explanation, I don't see how ticket_work table comes into picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines (completely untested):

```
SELECT users, tickets.time_spent, 
       (SELECT count(tickets.id) FROM tickets 
        WHERE tickets.assigned_to = users.id) as TotalTickets
FROM tickets LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_work ON ticket_work.ticket_id = tickets.id 
JOIN users where tickets.assigned_to = users.id
```

If you actually meant something else then please clarify the task at hand and the problems you are facing.